# Split files in java

Tags: java

I have a program to split .txt files that divides it in 101 files. The file that must be divided [File.txt](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1EOryaMjmlmtv1lHe7TwIduqszc0hmaq9) contains url separated by `\n`. The fact is that the program divides the file in equal parts and when it reaches the maximum size it cuts the url and starts a new file. How can I do to split it in a size that don't overshoot 1Mb and contains the url well splited?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class readfile {
    public static int SubfileName;
    public static int[] Murl = new int[2000000];
    public static int x = 0;
    public static long usemem = 0;
    public static long Numberofmailto = 0;
    static byte[] subfich; //Subfile data (global var)
    static long NumberUrl;
    static int[] indURL; //Indices de las URLs en "subfich"

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the file name like url.txt to read but it should be in E:\\url\\");
        String name = in.nextLine();
        readfile(name);

        try {
            //now create 100 subfile 
            GeneraFicheros();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // not used 
    public static void readfile(String filename) {
        try {
            // file path
            leeSubfichero("E:\\url\\" + filename);

            creaIndices();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    //read danger file
    static void leeSubfichero(String nomfich) throws IOException { // read file
        File fich = new File(nomfich);
        int tam = (int) fich.length(); //Tamaño bytes // size byte
        subfich = null;
        subfich = new byte[tam];
        try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fich)) {
            NumberUrl = fis.read(subfich);
            // find the mailto urls
        }
    }


    static void creaIndices() {
        // 1. Count the number of URLs
        int n = 0;
        int x = 0;
        boolean dangerurl = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < subfich.length; i++) {
            if (subfich[i] == 10) {
                n++;
            }
        }

        //2. Store separators position
        indURL = null;
        indURL = new int[n];
        //Murl = new int[n];
        int k = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < subfich.length; i++) {
            if (subfich[i] == 10) {
                indURL[k++] = i;
            }
        }
    }

    // create 100 files
    public static void GeneraFicheros() throws Exception {
        String zero = "00";
        RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile("E:\\url\\danger.txt", "r");
        long numSplits = 100; //divid in 100 subfiles
        long sourceSize = raf.length();  // danger.txt file size
        long bytesPerSplit = sourceSize / numSplits; // number of bytes each file will have
        long remainingBytes = sourceSize % numSplits;

        int maxReadBufferSize = 8 * 1024; //8KB
        for (int destIx = 1; destIx <= numSplits; destIx++) {
            // each literation create a new file like 000 
            System.out.println("Escrito Subfichero " + zero + destIx + ".txt");
            runtime();
            if (destIx > 9) {
                zero = "0";
            }

            // write the file with name like 000.txt
            BufferedOutputStream bw = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("E:\\url\\" + zero + destIx + ".txt"));
            if (bytesPerSplit > maxReadBufferSize) {
                // total number of bytes to read
                long numReads = bytesPerSplit / maxReadBufferSize;
                // total number of bytes remaining for other files
                long numRemainingRead = bytesPerSplit % maxReadBufferSize;
                for (int i = 0; i < numReads; i++) {
                    readWrite(raf, bw, maxReadBufferSize);
                }
                // if bytes are remaining write the file
                if (numRemainingRead > 0) {
                    readWrite(raf, bw, numRemainingRead);
                }
            } else {
                readWrite(raf, bw, bytesPerSplit);
            }
            bw.close();
        }
        // if dividion didn't work extra store here 
        if (remainingBytes > 0) {
            BufferedOutputStream bw = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("split." + (numSplits + 1) + ".txt"));
            readWrite(raf, bw, remainingBytes);
            bw.close();
        }
        raf.close();
    }


    // write 8kb each time in the file
    static void readWrite(RandomAccessFile raf, BufferedOutputStream bw, long numBytes) throws IOException {
        byte[] buf = new byte[(int) numBytes];
        int val = raf.read(buf);
        if (val != -1) {
            bw.write(buf);
        }
    }

    static long startTime = System.nanoTime();

    public static void runtime() {
        long endTime = System.nanoTime();
        long totalTime = endTime - startTime;
        double seconds = (double) totalTime / 1000000000.0;
        System.out.println("Toatl seconds" + seconds);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to split the file into 101 parts of equal size or do you want to split it into files not exceeding 1 MB?

Comment: I want to split into files not exceding 1Mb. It is not needed that the files have the same size

Comment: Meanwhile, you want to achieve limiting the size of a file?

Then check the correct answer on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39092861/limit-file-size-while-writing-in-java

Comment: Now is in english @GhostCat

Comment: Better: but please remove all these pointless empty lines. Code is written for human readers.

Comment: @KPP i want to do that but with the entire url

Answer (score 4):

There's no way to do this job, the way you've set up the code. Your code is fundamentally based on bytes (which makes it impossible to read something like a newline character, which is a character, not a byte), and it 'precalculates' how much to read, which also makes it impossible. Imagine there's a URL in your input file that is really long; almost as long as the required size.

Finally, there's no feasible way to say: "Split this file into exactly 100 parts, but do it in a way that EVERY file is smaller than totalsize/100... and also don't cut any lines in half." – there will probably be 101 files, there might even be 250 files. There might also be only 1 file, if the entire file is just one very long URL.

You'd have to specify exactly what you want your program to do before writing it.

Some tips:

- Use `Files.newBufferedReader`, passing in the charset. You need to move away from `InputStream` because that's for bytes, not characters.
- Read an entire line into memory, then and only then decide whether this line can be added to the current 'segment' you're writing, or if you need to make a new one because otherwise the segment you're writing would become too large.